# Recommended approach in finding IdentityServer files in GitHub

Tags: github, identityserver4

In looking for the IClientStore.cs file in GitHub, in the:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/44651bea9b02c992902639b21205f433aad47d03/src/EntityFramework.Storage/src/Stores/ClientStore.cs#L20

the cref for IClientStore shows as: IdentityServer4.Stores.IClientStore.

In navigating to: IdentityServer4/src/IdentityServer4/src/Stores/, the IClientStore.cs file is not there.

Instead, after a general search in GitHub, I found it in:
IdentityServer4/src/Storage/src/Stores/IClientStore.cs

Based on the initial cref above, how would we know to find IClientStore.cs in this Stores directory under "Storage"?

Is there a different recommended approach in finding IdentityServer4-related files in GitHub, and if so, would much appreciate a link to the material.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fetch the repo and use some proper SDK to for C# to browse the code around, it will provide you with superior features.

Comment: Hi Vidmantas - I think your idea is a sound one.  However, after trying 'dotnet restore' at both a sln and project level, as well as "Restore nuget packages" at the sln level, the cloned IdentityServer4 continues to have multiple errors and redlines (e.g. Predefined type "System.Object" is not defined or imported).  Is there a resource you can link me to that can show me some pointers on how to apply an SDK to restoring this repository?

Comment: If you just use something like Visual Studio 2019 SDK, and clone the repo it should work out of the box to build and restore the solution.

Comment: Ok. So just to be sure, not all solutions available in this repo work, correct?  For example, I know these solutions work:
 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/samples/Quickstarts    However, when attempting to use the solutions here, multiple errors (e.g. system.object is not defined or imported) appear: 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/master/src

Comment: They should work fine, the errors you are describing are unlikely to be related to these particular solutions.